# Add an ASP Button inside a asp table cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I have an ASP.NET Table that has rows added to it through C# and I was wondering is it possible to add an ASP Button inside a cell using C# code behind? I have looked around and not found anything that relates to what I am trying to do/

Comment: can you post the C# or markup that you have now ?

Comment: You should use a repeater control....

Comment: Something like `table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "Some Button" });`

Comment: @habib that's great, Just what I needed just didn't know the syntax, thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

```
Button button=new Button();
button.Text="Hello, world!";
table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(button);
```

Create the button, set its properties and then add it to the `Controls` collection of the control you want to add it to. Remember that you should do this in `Page_Init` in order to maintain ViewState for dynamic controls (or manually add the control to the ViewState).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void AddButton()
    {

          // Create new row and add it to the table.
          TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
          Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);
          for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= cellCnt; cellCtr++) {
             // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
             TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
             tCell.Text = "Row " + rowCtr + ", Cell " + cellCtr;
             tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
           Button bt = new Button();
           bt.text = "Click Me";
           bt.OnClick += OnClick;
           tRow.controls.add(bt);

    void GreetingBtn_Click(Object sender,  EventArgs e)
    {
      // do whatever you want to do 
    }
```